# How do I test or verify ZFS encryption is working?

Tags: solaris, encryption, zfs, testing

How do I test or verify that the ZFS encryption is working, especially when running as a Samba share?

Like if I create a ZFS pool with encryption=on, how can I tell whether a file is being properly encrypted or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use ZDB to see the on disk data, which will help you to know whether file is encrypted. Read the file after encryption and take checksum this should be same previously. This may validate any corruption.

Comment: My apologies for not asking the question properly. So a little bit more background information. There is some stuff that I want to secure on my server.

Comment: (whoops, hit enter too early)

The thing that I've been able to find out is that if I set it up with encryption, it will prompt me for the passphrase by default. If I unmount and try to remount it with the wrong passphrase, it won't mount. But when I either do zpool list or zfs list, it is able to show that (if I have a big enough file) that there is something there, but you can't see what it is. I want to make it that you can't even tell that it's there. Or that if you CAN see it, it should be a garbled mess. Hope you understand what I am talking about or what I am TRYING to say.